# ASP.NET MVC Razor - Linkshare - Increase Image Size

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I just downloaded the Microsoft.Web.Helpers package from nupack and added linkshare to my site using @Linkshare.GetHtml() syntax. It works extremely well - except the icons for social sites are tiny. Does anyone know of any way to increase these to a larger size? Looking at the API I don't see anything but perhaps there is something on the CSS level?

Thanks in advance,

JP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not built into the API. I'm not even sure if the various services provide icons that are larger than 16x16 pixels. You could manually modify the style that the control emits:

```
@(new HtmlString(LinkShare.GetHtml().ToHtmlString().Replace("width:16px", "width:32px")))
```

But this is a bit ugly. Why do you need for them to be larger (when most sites on the Internet are doing fine with the current size?)

Comment: Thanks Marcind. It's an ugly solution but one I may have to live with. 16*16 seems tiny to me. I've seen examples of similar icons in 32*32 and they look much better to me. At the very least I think it would be nice to implement an override to allow an array of images (or likewise) to be specified to override the default icons...

Comment: Hi @marcind @jp do you know if its possible to replace current image location for the icons displayed?. It seems that they request icons to each provider when a webpage is served and I would like to store images locally. thanks in advance